# Right way to delete record from array in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I want to be able to click a delete button for an item in a list, send an HTTP DELETE, and then have the record actually deleted only if the API returns a success code.

Here is my current code:

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        removeFoo: function() {
            var foo = this.get('model');

            var onFail = function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
                foo.rollback();
            };

            foo.deleteRecord();
            foo.save().then(function() {}, onFail);
        }
    }
});
```

This basically works ... except that the foo is removed from the DOM at the point of `save`, and if `rollback` is called, it is added again, but at the end of the array of `Foo` objects.

I could sort that array after the `rollback`, but that doesn't seem like the right approach. Is there a better ember.js pattern for this common situation?

Answer (score 2):

I would use an [ArrayController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html); with it, each item gets its own `ItemController` where you can have a flag `isVisible`.

So, when you delete/undo you can toggle that property.

To avoid saving items that are in the DOM, but hidden, I see two options:

1. Leave them there and when saving the whole array skip the ones with `isVisible = false`.
2. Add a timer that after X secs removes from the DOM the items where `isVisible = false`.

The delete/save, from the DOM and API, could be part of the ItemController, kind of adding a "self destruct" to each item.

Depending on the interaction that you want in the UI, those instructions can be rearranged. The building blocks will remain the same: ArrayController / ItemController.

Answer (score -1):

the logic will be don't delete any thing unless you get a success from server,then it will work fine

Comment: OK, but isn't it the `deleteRecord` along with the `save` that causes ember to sent the HTTP DELETE? I don't know how to get a success before I try to delete.

Comment: then delete it from your array model and always refresh that array from server after delete operation, this would give the updated data in your ui

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that you haven't worked with Ember so much.